# How to redirect after a JavaScript timer has expired?

Tags: javascript

Wishing to change the code as soon as this timer (See code) has expired.
I am working on a fun auction project for a friend of mine and when the time has run out I would like the page to change so nobody can place any more bids. 
All bids are timed so I could just check to see if anybody placed a bid after the expire but that is not very nice. If I could get it done auto, that would be great.
So at the moment it will say "EXPIRED!" but what should I place there so that no more bids can be set?

Should you wish to see more code, just let me know.
Thanks in advance.

```
CountDownTimer('01/31/2016 7:1 PM', 'countdown');

function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
{
    var end = new Date(dt);

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<span class="date">EXPIRED!</span>';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'Time Left = ';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += '<span class="date">' + days + ' D</span>';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML +=  '<span class="date">' + hours + ' H</span>';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML +=  '<span class="date">' + minutes + ' M</span>';
       // document.getElementById(id).innerHTML +=  '<span class="date">' + seconds + ' S</span>';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}
```

Comment: which url you want it to be redirected to?

Comment: why can't you just cancel the function that handles the bidding recognition instead of changing the page. unless you really want to change the page.

Answer (score 2):

in your code:

```
  if (distance < 0) {

        clearInterval(timer);
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<span class="date">EXPIRED!</span>';

        return;
    }
```

Add in your code:

```
`window.location.href="Your page to go to";`
```

Do this before the return.

Keep in mind that your html "Expired!" (may) not appear on the page because it will redirect immediately.

Comment: Thanks, I could have the word Expired on the redirected page.